# What exactly is the LL(k) grammar condition?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers, ll-k

I have a bit of trouble understanding the definition of LL(k) grammars.

[Here](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse756/cse756su32.xht) it's defined as:

> for every pair of production rules 
>   $A\rightarrow
> α$
>    and 
>   $A \rightarrow
> β$
>    the following condition holds.
>    $\text{FIRST}_k$
>   (
>    $\text{α FOLLOW}_k$
>   (A)) $\cap$
>    $\text{FIRST}_k$
>   (
>    $\text{β FOLLOW}_k$
>   (A))
>   $=\emptyset$

What does this mean concretely? What is the subscript $_k$?
Why is it for a "pair of production rules"?

Comment: 1) It means what's written there. 2) You need to unfold the definitions to figure out what $k$ means there; is comes from LL(k), obviously, a part of the definition you left out. 3) You check out pairs because you want to make sure there are no conflicts you can not resolve with $k$ items lookahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a definition of a *strong* LL(k) grammar.

First of all, see Raphael's comment.

In short, the condition means that while parsing $A$ you can choose the next production rule in a deterministic manner using **only** the next $k$ lookahead symbols.

An important thing is you don't need any context for that decision, i.e. you don't need to remember the previous steps in the left-most derivation that led you to the non-terminal $A$ to parse $A$ itself.

By the way, every LL(1) grammar is strong, but there are non-strong LL(k) grammars, $k > 1$.

If you need a more detailed explanation, then I think it's better to use a book for that (it's too long for an answer here). I'd suggest "Parsing Techniques - A Practical Guide" by Dick Grune et al.